# Find a Control in Asp.net Listview Inside the Selected Item Template

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I'm converting functionality from an asp.net Gridview to a Listview.  In the gridview when the selected item changed I would grab a value from a label in the selected row and write it to a different label outside of the gridview.

```
Protected Sub grdModules_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles grdModules.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim lblModuleTitle As Label = grdModules.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblModuleTitle")
    lblCurrentModule.Text = lblModuleTitle.Text

End Sub
```

In a Listview, there isn't a "SelectedRow" concept but a SelectedItem.  However you can't do findcontrol against the selected item.  When I try to do the following (I get a null reference exception):

```
Protected Sub listviewModules_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles listviewModules.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim lblModuleTitle As Label = CType(listviewModules.FindControl("lblModuleTitle"), Label)
    lblCurrentModule.Text = lblModuleTitle.Text

End Sub
```

Does anyone know the way to find a control inside the selected item template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling FindControl on the whole ListView, rather than just the selected item. This should work:

```
Dim lblModuleTitle As Label = CType(listviewModules.Items(listviewModules.SelectedIndex).FindControl("lblModuleTitle"), Label)
```

Comment: You are correct with after syntax change (if you want to update your post):
Dim lblModuleTitle As Label = CType(listviewModules.Items(listviewModules.SelectedIndex).FindControl("lblModuleTitle"), Label)
thanks!

Comment: One other thing to note: I struggled with this forever -- make sure you have the item you're trying to find in both the ItemTemplate and the SelectedItem template.  It won't find it unless it's in both.

Comment: Fixed - is it very obvious that I normally live in C# land?