# Find Control of Selected Item Template in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, nested

I have a listview nested inside another listview as such:

```
<asp:ListView ID="LV_Tickets" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQL_Tickets" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" OnPreRender="LV_Tickets_PreRender" DataKeyNames="TicketNum">

<!--These are the templates that do not apply to the question-->

<SelectedItemTemplate>
<asp:ListView ID="LV_TicketProd" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ChargeID" DataSourceID="SQL_TicketProducts" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" OnPreRender="LV_TicketProd_PreRender">
</SelectedItemTemplate>
```

I am confused on how I am able to retrieve the listview in my C# code. I know that with an Insert Item I can use the `LV_Tickets.InsertItem.FindControl` function, but for the `SelectedItem` I cannot use this function.

What I am currently trying is using the selected value of the listview for the index of the main listview:

```
ListView LV_TicketProd = (ListView)(LV_Tickets.Items[LV_Tickets.SelectedIndex].FindControl("LV_TicketProd"));
```

And once I have retrieved the nested listview I am trying to access a label:

```
((Label)LV_TicketProd.InsertItem.FindControl("TicketNumLabel")).Text = LV_Tickets.SelectedDataKey[0].ToString();
```

There are no errors being thrown with this process, but when I try to set the Text of the label like I have above, nothing is happening.

How should I go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have time to research it now, I will check it tomorrow. I delete my answer !

Comment: Alright, I think that it has something to do with the ListView being unique to every selected Index.

Comment: Check this it is for VB but probably you can use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204747/find-a-control-in-asp-net-listview-inside-the-selected-item-template

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying right now. I will update my question to show what I am trying.

Comment: Well, I feel like a complete idiot! The code that I was posting is working, but the text was white on a white background. Sorry for wasting your time...